# Change Azure AD Guest User's Source from "Microsoft Account" to "External AAD" (Azure B2B)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure Active Directory "ddddd" (hosted at xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com) with a Guest User that has ALREADY responded to an invitation.  But he responded with his Microsoft personal account instead of his work account (both have the same email address).  In the user profile, I see the source is currently "Microsoft Account".

This Active Directory "ddddd" is linked to Azure DevOps (Team Services) organization "ttttt" (i.e. the Directory setting of the "ttttt" DevOps organization is connected to my Active Directory "ddddd"). This user is already set up in "ttttt" and linked properly.

How do I re-invite or directly update the user profile so the Source is tied to "External Azure Active Directory" linked to his work place (which is an on-prem Active Directory linked through ADFS to Office 365 via yyyyy.onmicrosoft.com)?

One idea that occurs to me is to delete the user and re-create in Azure AD "ddddd" (at xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com), re-invite and ask him to accept the invitation using his work address (via adfs to yyyyy.onmicrosoft.com).

So my second question is: will recreating the user affect the user in my Azure DevOps "ttttt" ?  The email address of his work and personal Microsoft account is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, Azure AD doesn't support changing the authentication type of an external (guest or member) user, so if the user is authenticating with MSA and you'd prefer they use their Azure AD credentials, you'll have to delete their existing guest account and re-invite them with instructions that they should use their Azure AD credentials to accept.

As for the Azure DevOps tenant, I'm less familiar with that set up but if those are really separate tenants doing this operation in ddddd shouldn't affect ttttt.

Comment: Hi this answer was same at today ? or Microsoft have implement functionnality to change the Guest User's Source Account ? Because we have a customer they're migrated to AAD last week and thoses account doesn't work with multi organization on our Teams Tenant.  Thanks in  advance.

Comment: @pascalsanchez The answer is still accurate regarding our current capabiliites.

Comment: Thanks, we have created a powershell that can be delete user , adding thoses guest user and adding thoses to all they Team . But i have some problem because thoses user lost all existing conversation 1:1 . They have way to remap existing conversations 1:1 on MsTeam from old guest account to the news guest account ? Otherwise the email off all guest user was the same they have moved to AAD but they email doesn’t have change . Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Teams, but AFAIK there isn't a way to get 1:1 conversations back once the account is deleted (since I think they're tied to the user object rather than the email address).  Might be worth posting the question in a Teams forum to confirm though!

Comment: @sanpas have you had any success on the remapping 1:1 conversations for guest accounts issue?